# Cookie и private api instagram

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram

Как получить и сохранить(для дальнейшего использования) cookie при использовании [instagram private api](https://instagram-private-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-instagram_private_api)? Искал долго и ничего не нашел.

```
from instagram_private_api import Client

user_name = 'YOUR_LOGIN_USER_NAME'
password = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'

api = Client(user_name, password)

# получаем объект
cookie_jar = api.cookie_jar

# далее извлечь куки, куда-то записать
```

А потом как их применить не понятно

```
from instagram_private_api import Client

user_name = 'YOUR_LOGIN_USER_NAME'
password = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'

api = Client(user_name, password, cookie = ?)
```

В документации написано: "cookie: Saved cookie string from a previous session"
Но там несколько строк cookie.

Answer (score 1):

я использовал код чужой и немного изменил его, специально для сохранения куки и все записывал в БД

```
def to_json(python_object):
    if isinstance(python_object, bytes):
        return {'__class__': 'bytes',
                '__value__': codecs.encode(python_object, 'base64').decode()}
    raise TypeError(repr(python_object) + ' is not JSON serializable')

def onlogin_callback(api, username):
    cache_settings = api.settings
    cookies.set(username, json.dumps(cache_settings, default=to_json))
    print('[I] New auth cookie file was made: {0!s}'.format(username))


def login(username, password):
    device_id = None
    try:
        username_cookie = cookies.get(username)
        if not username_cookie:
            # settings file does not exist
            print('[W] Unable to find auth cookie file: {0!s} (creating a new one...)'.format(username))
            api = Client(
                username, password,
                on_login=lambda x: onlogin_callback(x, username))
        else:
            cached_settings = json.loads(username_cookie)
            device_id = cached_settings.get('device_id')
            # reuse auth settings
            api = Client(
                username, password,
                settings=json.dump(cached_settings, sys.stdout))

            print('[I] Using cached login cookie for "' + api.authenticated_user_name + '".')

    except (ClientCookieExpiredError, ClientLoginRequiredError) as e:
        print('[E] ClientCookieExpiredError/ClientLoginRequiredError: {0!s}'.format(e))

        # Login expired
        # Do relogin but use default ua, keys and such
        if username and password:
            api = Client(
                username, password,
                device_id=device_id,
                on_login=lambda x: onlogin_callback(x, username_cookie))

    except ClientLoginError as e:
        print('[E] Could not login: {:s}.\n[E] {:s}\n\n{:s}'.format(
            json.loads(e.error_response).get("error_title", "Error title not available."),
            json.loads(e.error_response).get("message", "Not available"), e.error_response))
        print('-' * 70)
        sys.exit(9)
    except ClientError as e:
        print('[E] Client Error: {:s}'.format(e.error_response))
        print('-' * 70)
        sys.exit(9)
    except Exception as e:
        if str(e).startswith("unsupported pickle protocol"):
            print("[W] This cookie file is not compatible with Python {}.".format(sys.version.split(' ')[0][0]))
            print("[W] Please delete your cookie file 'credentials.json' and try again.")
        else:
            print('[E] Unexpected Exception: {0!s}'.format(e))
        print('-' * 70)
        sys.exit(99)

    print('[I] Login to "' + api.authenticated_user_name + '" OK!')
    cookie_expiry = api.cookie_jar.auth_expires
    print('[I] Login cookie expiry date: {0!s}'.format(
        datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(cookie_expiry).strftime('%Y-%m-%d at %I:%M:%S %p')))

    return api
```

где cookies -- База данных

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но что-то я не понял как это использовать с этим https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api

Comment: Мы просто используем api чтобы залогиниться, или же для скачиваний историй фоток и тд, чтобы подписаться отписаться. Если честно, сам особо не разобрался, но переписал небольшую часть, и сейчас могу сохранять cookie в базу данных, а ключ записываю username пользователя и так получаю, думаю смог обьяснить)